# Deleting self-answered question gets "Delete this answered question" warning

Tags: discussion, warning, self-delete

While attempting to delete a question which was answered by myself, and with no other answers, I got the following warning:

> Delete this answered question?
>
> We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so
>   deprives future readers of this knowledge.
>
> Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account
>   being blocked from asking. Are you sure you wish to delete?

I understand that deleting your question when someone else has answered it is effectively nullifying the effort that person put into that answer, which is bad. But is it bad if the only answer that's deleted along with your question is your own?

Comment: This error can be confusing when there are [legitimate reasons to delete your own upvoted question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37692579#37692579).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The warning doesn't say *"deleting your question when someone else has answered it is effectively nullifying the effort that person put into that answer, which is bad"*

That is one reason not to delete a good question with a good answer. And it wouldn't apply to a self-answered question.

But it's not the only reason. And it's not the reason that the warning gives.

The warning says (my emphasis):

> We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because **doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge**.

And that applies equally to self-answered questions as to questions answered by others.

Answer (score 4):

While I understand with the sentiment of [EnergyNumbers's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243023/351462), **there are some scenarios where it makes sense to delete a self-answered question.**

Take for example the following poorly received self-answered question.

[image: Example of a bad self-answered question]

Thankfully, there is a workaround.

**If you were the only one to answer the question, delete your own answer first. Once the answer has been deleted, you should be able to delete your question without any issues.**

Comment: That's... hardly a reason. You're talking about intentionally reversing a migration, which is already an extremely rare issue, and becomes even more rare in considering only a migrated question with a single upvoted self-answer. While yes, that bypass works, we still don't recommend it and there's no saying a moderator or the community wouldn't at some point undelete it anyways for any situation that isn't a 1 in a million migration that needs to be rejected.

Comment: @animuson I've provided a much more common example of why self-deletion can sometimes be necessary.