# Self-deletion gives warning because of negative-score answer

Tags: discussion, warning, self-delete

The following question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/298164/what-does-club-mean-in-this-context gives me a warning when I try to delete it, because there's an answer there.

The problem is, it has a net score of -2 (+1/-3).

Why is deleting an answer that has a negative net score, along with a poorly received question, a bad thing?

Comment: The answer score is not being checked. Not sure if on purpose or just an overlook. Anyway, same as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243022/deleting-self-answered-question-gets-delete-this-answered-question-warning) by all means.

Comment: On deeper look, I believe the auto-ban algorithm also doesn't care for answers score. When it detects a deleted question with answers, it add to the "bad points" towards the ban. Again, bug or not? Not in my power to know.

Comment: Well, it's deleted now, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because the answer may currently have a net negative score but its provider has already spent some time posting it, and is still able to improve it via editing to reach what will hopefully be a net positive score.

The reason for that warning is documented in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/215590) to [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) - but for another more authoritative perspective on why, see [Does systematic self-deleting need to be prevented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented)

Comment: Having a negatively scored question doesn't prevent deletion of the question