# Warning before deleting a question

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, warning

This has already happened to me several times:

- a user posts a question;
- I provide an answer;
- the user deletes the question.

I know that the person who asked the question can do this at will if my answer is the only answer and if it got no upvotes. And I do not intend to ask to change that. But I think that, in this situation, the user who asked the question should get a warning saying something like “Someone took the trouble of writing and posting an answer to your question. Are you sure that you want to delete it?”

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243022/369802 < I'm not sure if that was a queston with a zero score answer (but guessing it must've been as the upvote limit was added [in '11](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/74471/369802))... but it seems it's already in place?

Comment: @ColleenV Sure. I've done that in the past. And at least once the person who deleted the question upvoted my answer and apologized.

Comment: In this case (I assume you refer to the most recent), the person won't upvote, they deleted their account three seconds after the question (which I have undeleted). In general: It's not a dead horse, you may flog it. Err, I mean fl**a**g it.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell is correct, I tried to delete a question with answer, and got a big warning: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmJZp.png.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Then I think that I will delete this request.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Feel free to chose between deleting or leaving this as a duplicate so others can more easily find this information. (I wonder if there may be a more appropriate post to close against than the one I linked you, though)...